# Multiple iPhones and iPads with same Apple id

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, apple-id

My husband has his personal iPhone 5s and iPad Air 2 and he also has an iPhone 6 and iPad Air 2 for his work. He wants to change the "work iPhone 6 and iPad Air 2" to a new Apple id not associated with his personal Apple id (icloud ??). I am trying to help, but I am not familiar with Apple iPhones etc. He uses his personal email for his Apple id for all of devices, but separate email addresses.

How do I change his work devices without losing contacts, pictures etc. I am not sure if all devices are uploading information into the iCloud - (how can I find out?).

I am so frustrated with reading so many things on the internet, I am scared to try to accomplish this for him. He doesn't have a clue on any tech things, so he is of no use to me to help.

Also, he wants to change his personal iPhone 5s to an iPhone 6 Plus (without losing his stuff).

I think I need some really good to help me to accomplish this without losing any contacts, photos, etc. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can help, but it will have several steps  that need to be covered properly so that he can be satisfied with the switch. I can also let you know now, that if he is using iCloud, by default the photos and contacts belong to that iCloud. The exception to the rule is if he backs up those photos to a hard drive and if his contacts came from his email address (Gmail, Yahoo, AOL, etc.) then he wont have to worry too much about the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Sure I can help, but this will take time to cover all of the bases. I'll keep updating this answer as I update it. I'll even comment when I update it.

1st thing 1st you want to make sure that all of his devices have a backup. While this may seem tedious it's a crucial step in migrating and changing accounts and devices. We want to do this 1st so that nothing is accidentally lost, locked or disappeared. You can either do an iTunes backup over the computer, although I personally recommend an iCloud backup since its 1 less device that you have to open and use, and you can do it right on the iPhone/iPad as long as it has WiFi access and is charging/has a decent amount of battery life.

To backup to iCloud, 1st make sure that he has iCloud on in settings (Settings -> Click his name -> Click on iCloud -> Scroll down to iCloud Backup (if he's logged in he should see it) - Click on iCloud backup and then make sure its on (green) and then Backup now (unless he has a backup and its recent with no changes made on the device's information - aka: contacts, messages, photos, etc). The other way (for older devices) is to go to Settings -> iCloud and then iCloud Backup.

If thats done with all of his devices then the next step is to copy all photos on these devices to a PC. It's easier that way rather than to deal with iCloud. If his iCloud photo library is on (Settings -> Click his name -> Click on iCloud -> Click on Photos -> Make sure iCloud Photo Library is on aka green) then he may not have direct physical access to his photos since the cloud has already begun uploading them. If there are photos that he can't access from his device but they are on the iCloud, there is a way to also download them from a computer. He will need to know his Apple ID email (usually in settings -> click his name -> email thats under his name) and password.

If you aren't familiar with extracting photos from these iPhones/iPads leave a comment and then we can discuss those matters.

iCloud Backup - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977

---

Once the iCloud backups and the photo extraction is done, then you are ready to check his accounts and see if he has a Gmail, Yahoo, AOL email (basically 3rd party client that hosts their own web-based email). If he does then usually that email has his contacts saved to it. He can always check by signing into the email address on the web and then checking contacts. If all of them are there great, then we can move on to the next steps. If not then we need to make sure contacts is on in iCloud so that they are all backed up. There is a way to download your contacts list from iCloud on the web. If you need that pointer, let me know. Once those contacts are confirmed/backed up then we can move forward.

---

Comment: Oh thanks for this information and I am going to do it step by step! Although, his iPhones always say something to the effect iCloud storage is full"! Is that a problem? I thought I would ask this first! Sorry, I don't know how to address you, but THANKS!!! I just saw Melvin Jefferson, so thank you SIR!!

Comment: Yes that's my name lol. Yes if iCloud mentions storage, then he may had filled up his free 5GB storage amount. Now if you guys are interested, depending on his country he can purchase an affordable storage increase that will remove that message and allow him to have his stuff backed up. In the USA, its 50 GB for just $0.99 a month (which is $12 a year). What country are you in? I can check the prices for your region. If you guys wish not to pay for the storage increase then we can always use iTunes on the computer, but the process will take longer since you'd have to do them all 1 by 1.

Comment: Sir, we are in Texas (USA) :) Do you think we will not be able to back up in the iCloude without paying for extra GB space? I just went on his personal iphone and clicked settings> name> then iCloud wanted his Apple id PSWD, I entered it and then a message came up and said, a code (2 - 3 digits) would be sent to his other devices and I called my husband and he said he got a notification that his iPhone was trying to be acccessed in Orlando, FL?? No codes were in that notification. What the heck. So I cancelled out and I am back to the settings. I am so confused. We live in Texas. :(

Comment: He has so many things going to the iCloud, and the iCloud is turned on in hiis personal iphone, but if I turn off say, notes it says something all notes will be deleted. Although, I really don't think there are any notes he has ever done. I'm sure he doesn't know how to use it. The only things that are not on are these things:

Mail, Keychain, iBooks, weather

Comment: By the way, I dowloaded on his laptop in a folder, all of his photos, just in the event something went wrong, but that was before I found this site to get some real help! I only have his perosnal phone, since he had to take his work stuff and personal iPad to work today.

Comment: I see. So he actively uses iCloud. If you rather use the computer then sure you can skip the payment. Although I recommend it just because for whatever reason if you don't have access to the PC, you wont be able to access those backups. I think it may be better if we converse via conference phone call just so that its easier for us to communicate. He has alot going on with his iPhones.

Comment: Smart move! Excellent

Comment: Do you call me or I call you to figure this mess out? I can do it in about 30 minutes or whatever is best for you Sir!

Comment: Do you have any messenger apps where I can reach you at? So I can give you my number.

Comment: I'm on a desktop PC, so I don't have one on here, but I do on my cell phone. The iPhone 6 plus is mine which is what he wants to change to, but I just got it last week and haven't used it much at all. I can give you my number and you or I can erase it imediately, unless we are not allowed to do that on here. I have FB Messenger,texting, facetime, iMessege on the iPhone 6 Plus....

Comment: My normal phone is a Note 3 and I know how to use that one. Should be move to CHAT, it's asking me then maybe we can figure out how to contact by phones!??

Comment: Try finding me on Facebook Messenger same name but my profile pic is my face with a city on it.

Comment: Okay, I will look for you on FB!

Comment: All I see are people's faces etc. No City with your name, Do you want to find me, mine is Debi Ann with a little bird face with a Christmas frame around it.

Comment: what happens when we move this discussion to chat?

Comment: okay I will call you at what time? I have a phone call in a couple minutes should be done in about 10 minutes.

Comment: Sure just let me know before you call so I can have it up.

Comment: going to call you

Comment: can I call you?

Comment: Yes you can, go ahead

Comment: Case Solved. ;)